# Where to find .ipa files uploaded through Xcode to iTunesConnect?

Tags: xcode, ipa

So I uploaded the build through Xcode, but I need the generated .ipa file that was uploaded to the store, where does Xcode store this file or how to find it?

Answer (score 0):

`Window` > `Organizer` > `Archives`

From there, if you want the archive just right-click > `Show in Finder`

You can then right-click the archive in Finder > `Show Package Contents` and get access to the .app, dsym files etc

Now, if you want the `.ipa`, you have to select the archive in the organizer > `Distribute App` > `<Anything other than AppStore>` and follow the steps of the guide.

Finally, [here is an article demonstrating the step mentioned above](https://needone.app/export-ipa-file-from-xcode-and-install-on-your-mobile/)